# What does Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS mean

Tags: indexing, lucene, analyzer

I know what does not_analyzed mean. In short the field will not be tokenized by specified Analyzer.

However, what does a **[NO_NORMS](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.Index.html#NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS)** means? I see the documentation, but please explain me in plain English. what is *index-time field and document boosting* and *field length normalization* ?

Comment: Hijacking this question for a little one of my own. What is difference between Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS and Fieldable.SetOmitNorms() method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It disables the following features:

- *index-time field and document boosting*: this means that the index will ignore any boosts you did to fields ([AbstractField.setBoost](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/core/org/apache/lucene/document/AbstractField.html#setBoost(float))) or documents ([Document.setBoost](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Document.html#setBoost(float))). A matching token will always be worth the same.
- *field length normalization*: this means that the index will ignore whether a matching token was in a short field (which should be more relevant) vs. a long field (less relevant). Again, a matching token will always be worth the same, no matter the length of the field.

Comment: so in short a field marked as NO_NORMS does not affect ranking of result at all, is that what this mean?

Comment: This is inexact. If a field is marked as NO_NORM, term matches on it DO affect ranking. Just its boost and length do not.

Comment: I didn't mean that a matching term doesn't affect ranking, I meant that it does in the same magnitude, no matter the field's length.

Comment: Great answer. Do you the difference between Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS and the Fieldable.SetOmitNorms() method?